# TypeScript create new instance from class in a static context

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to create new instances from a static method in a generic way?

I want to do something like:

```
class Base {
    static getInstance() {
         return new self(); // i need this line :)
    }
}

class Test extends Base {
}

class NextTest extends Base {
}

var test = Test.getInstance();
assert(test instanceof Test).toBe(true);

var nextTest = NextTest.getInstance();
assert(nextTest instanceof NextTest).toBe(true);
```

It would be really helpful if someone did something like this before and could help me. Maybe there is a JavaScript way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious... why would this be useful?

Comment: I am going to build TypeScript Models with an integrated RESTful Client. So you can import TestModel and call TestModel.objects.all() which needs to return a TestModel :D Somehow the objects class (actually it is the REST client) needs to know which Model to populate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hack :)

```
static getInstance() {
     return new this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I always tried my approach with a static property not with a method :D Similar to: "static prop: Manager = new Manager(new this);" - Which is not compiling :) I will go with a static method

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: `error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Comment: How one calls super? Doesn't work because I get the wrong type.

Answer (score -4):

You can also use class name itself which in your example is **Base**,

```
static getInstance() {
   return new Base()
}
```

Another example is below which uses ***Greeter*** class name inside static function called **createInstance**, you can test following example at [TypeScript Playground](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjii47wtYzSAhXDNiYKHTdwDy4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.typescriptlang.org%2FPlayground%2F&usg=AFQjCNGARK0TSZKU0vSHv2QTz_lLfKH5Pw&sig2=IzwgenrDcmIvpuhkVXYKwQ)

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }

    static createInstance(message: any) {
        return new Greeter(message);
    }
}

let greeter = Greeter.createInstance("world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was answered correctly 2 years ago. Your answer does not return subclasses as per the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update @mrm . Didn't notice about the sub classes requirement above. I was just trying out different codes and found an example with the Base class instead of 'this', just wanted to elaborate about using classname instead of this which also works if sub classing requirement isn't there, though haven't tested it out but I'll believe what you are saying as you already have tested it out. Thanks for pointing it out, helps the other users.